# Pegar um determinado valor num Foreach no Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, collection

Queria saber como eu faço para percorrer uma Collection e resultar um determinado valor? A Collection  funciona assim  e retornado vários valores de marcações de funcionários para ser impressas no ponto, existe dois pare metros que considera cada marcação `$markings->VF_ENTRADA` que retorna `S` para entrada e `N` para saída `$markings->HR_MARCACAO` que representa a hora dessa marcação eu to enfrentando um problema para pegar a hora final de saída, naturalmente essa ultima saída representando o fechamento do ponto seria  ultimo valor do array retornado porem pode haver casos de edição no DB. Resumindo eu queria pegar a maior hora `HR_MARCACAO` com valor `VF_ENTRADA = N`  que representaria a ultima saída do funcionário  assim fechando do ponto do dia.

> Esse e o codigo que estou usando para listar no Blade

```
  ($markings->VF_ENTRADA (RETORANAR VALOR = 'S' OU 'N'))

    <td class="pl-0 pr-0 pb-0 text-center">


           @foreach ($punchcard->markings as $markings)
              @if($loop->last)

                   {{$markings->HR_MARCACAO}}
              @endif

            @endforeach

    </td>
```

Eu estou usando `$loop->last` para retornar a ultima interação, mas e como eu disse pode haver casos de edição no DB logo esse valor poderia ser invalido para o resultado que quero.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Query de pesquisa

```
public function returnDataPonto($id,$periode_start,$periode_stop)
    {

      $worker=Workers::where('CD_FUNC',$id)->with('cargos')
                                         ->whereHas('punchcards',function($query)
                                        use($periode_start,$periode_stop){

    $date1 = $periode_start;
    $date2 = $periode_stop;

    $query->where('DT_PONTO','>=', $date1)
          ->where('DT_PONTO','<=', $date2);})     


          ->whereHas('punchcards.markings',function($query){
            $query->where('VF_ENTRADA', 'N');
            })
          ->first();

        return $worker;
    }
```

Comment: faz um dd($punchcard->markings) e posta na pergunta por favor

Comment: abre um markings por favor assim fica mais fácil para te orientar

Comment: Postei la, não deu para exibir o conteúdo  de cada marcação porque ficou truncado por causa do tanto de conteúdo.

Comment: Eu quero entender o retorno dos dados assim faço uma resposta bem clara

Comment: Postei o retorno em Json

Comment: HR_Marcacao é um time então?

Comment: Se você quer pegar HR_MARCACAO a partir de VF_ENTRADA ser N pode fazer isso simplemente com o Query Builder pow, se for isso que entendi posso montar um exemplo para você.

Comment: Isso mesmo e um time  que pega o momento exato da marcação

Comment: é isso que falei acima?? Pegar HR_MARCACAO a partir de VF_ENTRADA ser N ?

Comment: E assim quando um funcionário passa seu crachar e feito o registro da hora e se ele entrou ou saiu.

Comment: Eu entendi, mas você ta usando muito PHP e pouco banco, certas coisas deixa o banco fazer.

Comment: Eu postei a query de pesquisa que fiz da um olhadinha.

Comment: No caso dessa query eu  também utilizo  para pegar a hora de entrada também

Comment: Você pode usar a query a baixo que respondi com whereHas('markings',function($query){}) e validar o VF_ENTRADA

Comment: Tentei do jeito que disse, só que o relacionamento desapareceu e acabou não retornado nenhum valor nem mensagem de erro.

Comment: Posta o código para eu ver

Comment: Atualizei a resposta e coloquei where relacional para você entender o que eu disse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resposta da sua dúvida pode ser resolvida da seguinte forma:

No controller:

```
$marcacoes = Model::select('HR_MARCACAO')->where('VF_ENTRADA', 'N')->get(); //Dessa forma você pega somente o HR_MARCACAO do VF_ENTRADA n, se quiser todos dados além do HR_MARCACAO só tirar o select
```

Where relacional:

```
$worker=Workers::where('CD_FUNC',$id)->with('cargos')->whereHas('punchcards',function($query) use($periode_start,$periode_stop)
{
        $query->where('DT_PONTO','>=', $periode_start)->where('DT_PONTO','<=', $periode_stop);

})whereHas('punchcards.markings', function($query){
  $query->where('VF_ENTRADA', 'N');
})->first();
```

No blade:

```
@foreach($marcacoes as $marcao)
  @if($loop->last)

      {{$markings->HR_MARCACAO}}

   @endif
@endforeach
```

Se não te ajudar me responda que irei rever e te ajudar resolver.

Comment: Editei do jeito que disse, só estar pegando o relacionamento do Cargos. Editei meu código ai para ver.

Comment: e o retorno é qual?

Comment: Deu um loop  infinito, que ai próprio   laravel para kkk

Comment: Errado foi loop infinito não, eu acho que o que foi retornado foram todos os dados de `markings` sem relacionar a determinado funcionario

Comment: Olha seu banco se está certo, por que se estiver errado precisa refazer

Comment: certo ele ta, já  testei pegar dados  por  linha de comando foi tranquilo.

Comment: Faz um teste sem tudo isso de where só usa o ultimo whereHas e vê se retorna os dados

Comment: sem o where  não retorna nada não.Eu tô pensando num outro jeito pra tratar, pq  tipo assim na  primeira  versão que te mostrei ele retorna todas as marcações  que preciso a chave e eu conseguir separa-la  como a hora que o funcionário entra e a hora que ele sai e fecha o ponto que no caso seria a maior hora marcada.

Comment: Faz um mapa das suas tabelas alguma coisa deve está errado, pois eu tenho tabelas relacionado dessa forma e retorna certinho '-'

Comment: Cara a raiva que eu  tô passando eu ate faria viu, o problema de que e o DB da empresa e eles querem manter a integridade do DB, mas valeu assim mesmo Lucas Antonio ajudou bastante.